# Solving Regular Expressions with Repeating Patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have attempted some Regular Expressions from a past examination paper and I am struggling to understand how to derive an expression for them. These are the questions:

```
Words that contain two or more 3 letter sequence of
consonants separated by vowels (e.g. uncrinkle,
thymopsyche, xlyoglyphy, unwrongfully)

Words that contain 2 or more 2 letter sequences of
vowels (e.g. visionproof, steamier, preequip)
```

I am unsure how to approach them, my original attempt I just split them such that the patterns would match in a very long regex string, where I checked for three consonants split by vowels and then repeated that pattern in the regex twice, but I don't think that's a good solution, is there better, using groups? (I don't quite understand it)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+)?([^aeiou,.\s]{2,3}[a-zA-Z]+)/g
```

It will match the word with 2 or more 3 consonants. And for vowels, you can use:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+)?([aeiou]{2,3}[a-zA-Z]+)/g
```

How it works:

`(?:[a-zA-Z]+)?` selects everthing before the matching, and if there isn't anything, it ignores.

`[^aeiou,.\s]` `[aeiou]{2,3}` captures the consonants/vowels, the first regex ignores `,`, `.` and `\s`

And `[a-zA-Z]+` in the end selects the rest of the word.

Answer (score 0):

(First of all, the exact lists of consonants and vowels depend on your language. To save space, I'll use just bcd... for consonants and aei... for vowels.)

To match "words that contain two or more 3 letter sequences of consonants separated by vowels", you need to match three consonants, then a vowel (or multiple vowels; the sentence seems ambiguous to me), then three consonants.

```
[bcd...]{3}[aei...][bcd...]{3}
[bcd...]{3}[aei...]+[bcd...]{3}
```

To match "words that contain 2 or more 2 letter sequences of vowels", you need to simply match 2 vowels, then anything, and then 2 vowels. Again, it is ambiguous if the string "aeio" should be accepted, as it has two sequences of two vowels ("ae" and "io"). The solution would be one of the following:

```
[aei...]{2}[aei...bcd...]*[aei...]{2}
[aei...]{2}[bcd...]+[aei...]{2}
```

If you're supposed to detect whole words in a longer text, you can prepend each regex with `\b\S*` and append `\S*\b`, where `\b` means word break and `\S*` means any sequence of non-whitespace characters.

Groups and back references don't help here, because there is no repetition.

The "or more" part means that a single match is enough; if it was "exactly two", you would need to check that there aren't more such sequences, which would complicate things.